# How to fix the nginx url encoding issue?

Tags: nginx, utf-8

I want to use Nginx for my website, but Nginx has some issues with non-English URLs.
My target language is Russian.
Trying to solve this problem for a while now and I have absolutely no clue how to make it work.

I have a redirect on my index.php and there is a piece of code that basically just prints the path:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $cur_url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $path = explode( '/', trim($cur_url['path']));
    array_shift($path);
    echo $path[0];
?>
```

input: [http://192.168.1.17/привет](http://192.168.1.17/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82)

output: `%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82`

Here is my config file:

```
#/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

http {
    charset utf-8;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    ...
```

Output from wget -S

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Thu, 16 Jan 2020 14:21:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

It's really confusing and I don't even know where to dig next. Help, please. Thanks in advance

Edit:
Turns out that

```
    $path[0] == "%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82"
```

is true.

And I can pretty much work with what I have. But still, I want to find the full solution.

Comment: can you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

String `%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82` is url encoded form of `привет` (in UTF-8 encoding) in your request. Such url encoding is made by browser itself. So in fact nginx receives request with address `http://192.168.1.17/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82` and processes it in this form.

If you need to restore %D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82 to utf-8 string you must do it yourself. Usually it is done by php or similar backend. But if you want to use only nginx you can use its `lua` module